# Ordenar ID al guardar datos en Json con PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy desarrollando un prueba para guardar datos dentro de un .json como base de datos mas o menos asi:

```
<?php

//funciones ---------

function nuevoUsuario(){
return json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/usuarios.json'), true);
}

function crearUsuario($data){
$user = nuevoUsuario();
$data['id'] = rand(1000000, 2000000);
$user[] = $data;
escribeJson($user);
return $data;
}


function escribeJson($users){
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/usuarios.json', json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}


//crear ---------------

$user = [
'id' => '',
'name' => '',
'username' => '',
];

$errors = [
'name' => "",
'username' => "",
];

$esValido = true;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$user = array_merge($user, $_POST);

$esValido = validaUser($user, $errors);

if ($esValido) {
    $user = crearUser($_POST);

    image($_FILES['picture'], $user);

    header("Location: index.php");
}
}

?>

<!-- formulario -->

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input name="name">
<input name="username">
<button>Crear</button>
</form>
```

El codigo funciona bien y los datos se guardan asi:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mario 3",
    "username": "estepepemere3",
    "id": 1231322
  },
  {
    "name": "Pepe",
    "username": "estepepemere1",
    "id": 1590898
  }
]
```

El problema es que no logro hacer que el `id` se guarde arriba de `name` y no debajo. Dentro de los archivos `PHP` se puede leer bien y hasta modificar perfectamente, pero no se si el orden del `id` puede afectar al ser consultado con JavaScript o desde backend con node.js.

Espero se entienda lo que quiero decir.
Gracias!

Comment: No debería importar que el `id` esté al principio o al final. Pero fíjate que mareas tanto los datos que no logro entender tu lógica. Si se trata de escribir todos los datos en un JSON no entiendo por qué los escribes uno por uno en el archivo y no todos juntos,  y, parece que el `array_merge` sobra ... ¿hacer muerte del array sobre si mismo, por qué?  Creo que esas manipulaciones, por lo demás innecesarias, son las que están causando la situación que planteas.

Comment: Entiendo, trato de que el archivo `.json` sea la base de datos con un `id` de usuario, nombre, password, etc., solo datos simples para hacer pruebas. Use `array_merge` para mezclar valorres que provienen de la funcion `validaUser` que por cierto no la agregue en la pregunta, pero valida que los datos `name` sean un string o que permita un minimo de 6 caracteres

Comment: Para poder ayudarte mejor seria útil que muestras un pequeño extracto de los datos con los que trabajas en cada punto, usando `var_dump`. Das demasiadas vueltas en tu código, hay datos que no son evidentes (porque provienen de un archivo) y sin ver la realidad de los datos no se podría revisar/optimizar el código. Por ejemplo, el dato original que obtienes en  `$user`, ¿qué estructura tiene? Hay más interrogantes, como dije en mi anterior comentario: ¿qué justifica el uso de `array_merge`? ¿o el uso del array que tienes donde pones el comentario `-- crear`? ... En fin, un código que da mareo.